# chrome does not respect font-family ('PT Sans')

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, styles

I have a web-page written in `HTML`, in which I have a `button`. All the page respects the `font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif` except my button.

```
body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Here is the button element inside a table:

```
<button id="createCampaignButton" class="yellowButton" nowrap>CREATE NEW CAMPAIGN</button>
```

I also used `<style>` tag like below, it will change the font color but not the font family.

```
button {
          font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
          color: red
       }
```

I searched here but none of them was working for me.

My style-sheet:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

.yellowButton {
border: 0 solid #FFCC00;
width:100%;
/*height: 50px;*/
font-size: 16px; 
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #FFCC00; 
padding: 12px 20px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
border-radius: 2px;
outline:none;
}
.yellowButton:active {
  border: 0 solid #FFCC00;
  width:100%;
  /*height: 50px;*/
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #FFCC00; 
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #C2C2C2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: none;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Now I noticed that the problem is only with `'PT Sans'` font ! all other fonts work fine.

Comment: Could you share your entire stylesheet? It will be useful to see if any rules are overriding your body's styling.

Comment: @Brayniverse I added the regarding styles

Comment: Is very strange. Can you give a link to see in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved adding this line to the styles, as far as I understood, `button` inside `table` does not inherit styles from `body` styles. The main problem was that I should have cleaned the cache of the browser.

```
button{
        font-family:  'PT Sans', sans-serif;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have u included this file ??

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

If not just past in header.

Or If you want to in css, Use this

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic);
```

Comment: Try using " font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif !important; "

Answer (score 0):

You can use right click and "inspect" in chrome to see which styles are in use and are overriding the others.

If you inspect the element, you will see what is overriding what and also what is misspelled with a little yellow warning icon next to it.

Comment: the OP use `font-family` explicitly in the button, this is not the problem

Comment: That is true, my bad, sorry. Reading fast. Then I can only think of using bootstrap or something else that is overriding the styles. But I am sure inspect would help.

Comment: yes, you're right. Surely inspecting the code found some inherited style